# Stuck on login screen: Ubuntu 20.04 xrdp <> Windows 10 Remote Desktop

Tags: server, login, remote-desktop

I have xrdp installed on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS headless server and I'm using Remote Desktop in Windows 10.

I can login using xrdp as I have it set to run on startup, but I can't click enter while Remote Desktop'ed into the machine. I can select a user using the mouse, and enter the password, I just can't click enter.

I've tried a few different keyboards to no avail. I've also tried plugging the keyboard directly into the server to click enter to no avail.

Any ideas are appreciated :D